# How to interpret predictions from LightGBM

Tags: python, pandas, lightgbm

I am trying to obtain predictions from my LightGBM model, simple min example is provided in the first answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62555987/lightgbm-ranking-example/67621253#67621253). When I run the provided code from there (which I have copied below) and run model.predict, I would expect to get the predictions for the binary target, 0 or 1 but I get a continuous variable instead:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import lightgbm

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "query_id":[i for i in range(100) for j in range(10)],
    "var1":np.random.random(size=(1000,)),
    "var2":np.random.random(size=(1000,)),
    "var3":np.random.random(size=(1000,)),
    "relevance":list(np.random.permutation([0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,1,1]))*100
})

train_df = df[:800]  # first 80%
validation_df = df[800:]  # remaining 20%

qids_train = train_df.groupby("query_id")["query_id"].count().to_numpy()
X_train = train_df.drop(["query_id", "relevance"], axis=1)
y_train = train_df["relevance"]

qids_validation = validation_df.groupby("query_id")["query_id"].count().to_numpy()
X_validation = validation_df.drop(["query_id", "relevance"], axis=1)
y_validation = validation_df["relevance"]

model = lightgbm.LGBMRanker(
    objective="lambdarank",
    metric="ndcg",
)

model.fit(
    X=X_train,
    y=y_train,
    group=qids_train,
    eval_set=[(X_validation, y_validation)],
    eval_group=[qids_validation],
    eval_at=10,
    verbose=10,
)

model.predict(X_train)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would expect to get the predictions for the binary target, 0 or 1 but I get a continuous variable instead

You are using `LGBMRanker` so you are trying to rank your data by query group. You are not trying to classify if the query is relevant (1) or not (0).

To get the rank of each query id, you can use:

```
# Avoid SettingWithCopyWarning
train_df = df[:800].copy()  # first 80%
validation_df = df[800:].copy()  # remaining 20%

# Predict
y_pred = model.predict(X_train)

# Rank
train_df['rank'] = (train_df.assign(pred=y_pred).groupby('query_id')['pred']
                            .rank(method='dense', ascending=False).astype(int))
```

Output:

```
>>> train_df.head(20)
    query_id      var1      var2      var3  relevance  rank
0          0  0.310088  0.855698  0.812061          0     4
1          0  0.450598  0.178649  0.734282          1     1
2          0  0.767785  0.948723  0.554276          0     7
3          0  0.832502  0.768063  0.659054          0    10
4          0  0.184687  0.708391  0.205448          0     6
5          0  0.633676  0.886995  0.397744          0     9
6          0  0.323786  0.921241  0.228752          0     3
7          0  0.381342  0.712662  0.142029          0     8
8          0  0.993355  0.182123  0.104416          1     2
9          0  0.118358  0.032669  0.298469          0     5
10         1  0.508594  0.362492  0.600220          0     7
11         1  0.156516  0.624849  0.737191          1     1
12         1  0.420040  0.010797  0.522225          0     4
13         1  0.508450  0.691576  0.395909          0    10
14         1  0.840053  0.364863  0.439742          0     9
15         1  0.941446  0.640084  0.614170          0     8
16         1  0.804287  0.577919  0.590988          0     5
17         1  0.090188  0.166563  0.364991          0     3
18         1  0.124671  0.326929  0.577342          1     2
19         1  0.037713  0.383510  0.500487          0     6
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was a little bit unclear in my question (and my thinking). It was my understanding that LGBRanker was going to match whatever rank I had in the target variable, similar to say a Log Regression or something like that. Meaning if my target variable had say 10 ranks, it would match that and try to predict the rank in each qid. It was not my goal to obtain the ranking across qids, but this is a helpful answer nevertheless.

Comment: So my question would then be this: I am actually working with a dataset that doesn't have any ranks, but rather I am creating the rank variable based on my continuous variable (think of the y_pred). I rank them into 5 groups, because I am interested in the top 20%. I thus thought, by doing so, I would get y_pred that also produces the same type of prediction of 5 categories.